# UmbracoLog table

Tags: umbraco

In a load balanced server setup, our UmbracoLog table is receiving on the order of 50 records a second being written that all follow the same pattern (apologies for formatting)

```
**id    userId  NodeId  Datestamp   logHeader   logComment

1122069437  0   -1  41302.1891  System  Submitting calls to distributed servers

1122069438  0   -1  41302.1891  Custom  http://www.url.com/umbraco/webservices/cacheRefresher.asmx

1122069439  0   -1  41302.1891  System  Submitting calls to distributed servers

1122069440  0   -1  41302.1891  System  Distributed server push completed with no nodes reporting an error

1122069441  0   -1  41302.1891  System  Distributed server push completed with no nodes reporting an error

1122069442  0   -1  41302.1891  Custom  http://www.url.com/umbraco/webservices/cacheRefresher.asmx**
```

Over a 24 hour period, this results in a 6.9GB table and a database that's persistently running hot in terms of CPU and mem usage.

We've checked the web.config and umbraco.config settings files of other similar site setups, and there's no differences in terms of configuration.

We can disable the system level logging but we would lose other meaningful messages.

Can anyone help with isolating this issue?

TL;DR Umbraco,Log table being hammered with multiple calls every millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you have two options and you take both of them.

Report the issue on the issue tracker (issues.umbraco.org) so the guys can look into if it is something out of the ordinary.

Then to stop it you could do a custom build with the log messages commented out. See this file for the offending code: https://bitbucket.org/slace/umbraco/src/e9e2f67c6cae/umbraco/presentation/umbraco/cache/dispatcher.cs

Not ideal but could get you up and running and lighten the load on the DB server until you get a fix.

A bigger question is why that code would be running so often, might be worth a dig around in the code to see if you can see why. If you do find out do report it back to Umbraco HQ so they can fix it for other ;)

Comment: The issue is fixed in later versions of umbraco - we have now upgraded to latest. Before that, we added a sql agent job to update the date on all expired documents.

Cheers for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

We have identified the issue. It came down to expired documents and how umbraco 4.5.2 handles them.

After disassembling the dll, we found the culprit in CheckPublishing method in the publishingService class (umbraco.presentation):

```
foreach (Document d in Document.GetDocumentsForExpiration())
{
   library.UnPublishSingleNode(d.Id);
}
```

And the GetDocumentsForExpiration() runs the following query:

```
IRecordsReader dr = CMSNode.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("select distinct nodeId from cmsDocument where newest = 1 and not expireDate is null and expireDate <= @today", new IParameter[] { CMSNode.SqlHelper.CreateParameter("@today", DateTime.Now) });
```

So, umbraco runs this publishing service to check and unpublish the expired documents without actually updating the expiry date, which is used to fetch the documents that need to be expired/unpublished. Hence the documents are never expired (though they are unpublished).

Call(s) to distributed servers happen each time there is a change in the documents (publish, unpublish, save etc). Because of the publishingService and the code outlined above, these expired documents were unpublished each time the service run, resulting in many distributed calls (and database records being written).

The solution is to either clear out the expiry dates on these documents (manually or via SQL agent jobs) or to fix the Umbraco source code.

This bug was fixed in later versions of Umbraco (not sure which version it was fixed in, but I checked 4.11.3 and it has the fixed code).